# Sms is sent but not delivered - Twilio

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-php

I am sending sms from my PHP application using [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) API. I am using a trial account and I have registered phone numbers, one of witch is my own, personal phone number. The messages are sent but not delivered, no error messages, no exceptions, in logs they are recorded as 'sent'

1. I do have money left on my trial account (a bit more then 13$)
2. I did have contacted support and they've set they will check, but it's been several days now, no answer

Comment: Country in which i'm sending sms is also checked as allowed country.

Comment: There is no way, from the information you've supplied, we can help you with this question.

Comment: what information do you need to help me with my question?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey @shotex, can you email me your ticket number at philnash@twilio.com. I'll see if I can chase it up.

Answer (score 3):

Well, problem is solved, turns out it was a problem of downstream carrier. One of my countries mobile service providers (geocell in country Georgia) has blocked Twilio. We contacted them and in 2 days, they solved the problem. if you will ever have such problem, consider testing all mobile service providers in your country and contacting them if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#error-values

> Twilio has received a delivery receipt indicating that the message was not delivered. This can happen for a number of reasons including carrier content filtering, availability of the destination handset, etc.

I would assume its the carrier or handset. Are you using modern equipment and a popular carrier?

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.

Comment: my apologies it was done in error, though this could be the solution ..